# Why isn't this discord slash command working?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to upgrade all of my discord bots with slash commands, using the `discord_slash` package (now called `discord_interactions` I believe). However, when I run the following code, every time I use the slash command, it says "this interaction failed" on discord. A debugger and some debug text also prove that the function associated with the command isn't running at all. Here is my code(I think what I'm doing with the buttons is wrong, but that shouldn't matter in this case):
Why is this interaction failing?

```py
import discord
import discord_slash
from discord.types.components import ButtonComponent
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord.ui import Button

bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("we a'goin!")


guild_ids = ['guild id']
normalPollOptions = [
    {
        "name": "poll_title",
        "description": "Title of the Poll",
        "type": 3,
        "required": True
    },
    {
        "name": "option_1",
        "description": "First choice of the poll",
        "type": 3,
        "required": True
    },
    {
        "name": "option_2",
        "description": "Second choice of the poll",
        "type": 3,
        "required": True
    },
    {
        "name": "option_3",
        "description": "Third choice of the poll",
        "type": 3,
        "required": False
    },
    {
        "name": "option_4",
        "description": "Fourth choice of the poll",
        "type": 3,
        "required": False
    },
    {
        "name": "option_5",
        "description": "Fifth choice of the poll",
        "type": 3,
        "required": False
    },
    {
        "name": "option_6",
        "description": "Sixth choice of the poll",
        "type": 3,
        "required": False
    },
    {
        "name": "option_7",
        "description": "Seventh choice of the poll",
        "type": 3,
        "required": False
    },
    {
        "name": "option_8",
        "description": "Eighth choice of the poll",
        "type": 3,
        "required": False
    },
    {
        "name": "option_9",
        "description": "Ninth choice of the poll",
        "type": 3,
        "required": False
    },
    {
        "name": "option_10",
        "description": "Tenth choice of the poll",
        "type": 3,
        "required": False
    }
]


@slash.slash(name="normalpoll", description="Make a normal poll", guild_ids=guild_ids, options=normalPollOptions)
async def _normalpoll(ctx, poll_title, option_1, option_2, option_3=None, option_4=None, option_5=None, option_6=None, option_7=None, option_8=None, option_9=None, option_10=None):
    await ctx.send(content="hi!")
    optionParam = [option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4, option_5, option_6, option_7, option_8, option_9, option_10]
    options = [i for i in optionParam if not i is None]
    buttonList = [Button(label=i) for i in options]
    await ctx.send(components=buttonList)


bot.run('censored bot token')
```

Thanks!

Comment: is that all 10 user input type option, likw where the user would type in their choice manually, or is it some choices for the same option like `where do u live? a.usa b.uk c.asis d.australia` is your 10 options are like usa, uk in here?

Answer (score 0):

The options should be in a different format actually to make them work

You have to use `create_option` function from `discord_slash.utils.manage_commands` to create an option for your command

```py
import discord
import discord_slash
from discord.types.components import ButtonComponent
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_option
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord.ui import Button

bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("we a'goin!")


guild_ids = ['guild id']
normalPollOptions = [
    create_option(
        name="poll_title",
        description="Title of the Poll",
        type=3,
        required=True
    ),
    create_option(
        name="option_1",
        description="First choice of the poll",
        type=3,
        required=True
    ),
    create_option(
        name="option_2",
        description="Second choice of the poll",
        type=3,
        required=True
    ),
    create_option(
        name="option_3",
        description="Third choice of the poll",
        type=3,
        required=False
    ),
    create_option(
        name="option_4",
        description="Fourth choice of the poll",
        type=3,
        required=False
    ),
    create_option(
        name="option_5",
        description="Fifth choice of the poll",
        type=3,
        required=False
    ),
    create_option(
        name="option_6",
        description="Sixth choice of the poll",
        type=3,
        required=False
    ),
    create_option(
        name="option_7",
        description="Seventh choice of the poll",
        type=3,
        required=False
    ),
    create_option(
        name="option_8",
        description="Eighth choice of the poll",
        type=3,
        required=False
    ),
    create_option(
        name="option_9",
        description="Ninth choice of the poll",
        type=3,
        required=False
    ),
    create_option(
        name="option_10",
        description="Tenth choice of the poll",
        type=3,
        required=False
    )
]

@slash.slash(name="normalpoll", description="Make a normal poll", guild_ids=guild_ids, options=normalPollOptions)
async def _normalpoll(ctx, poll_title, option_1, option_2, option_3=None, option_4=None, option_5=None, option_6=None, option_7=None, option_8=None, option_9=None, option_10=None):
    await ctx.send("hi!")
    optionParam = [option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4, option_5, option_6, option_7, option_8, option_9, option_10]
    options = [i for i in optionParam if not i is None]
    buttonList = [Button(label=i) for i in options]
    await ctx.send(components=buttonList)

bot.run('censored bot token')
```

Tell me if its okay for you...

Comment: It did not work